# Video element disappears in Chrome when not using controls

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, webm

So - I **think** this is a browser bug. It came up in a much more complicated design/site, but I've had a good solid fiddle around, simplified my code and designs, etc, and have found the following:

When embedding `<video>` without a controls attribute in Chrome, triggering the video to play using javascript causes the video element to go blank.

http://jsfiddle.net/trolleymusic/2fHTv/

The blankness is a bit random, sometimes by rolling out of the element, it'll reappear. Sometimes you need to click/focus on something else, most of the time pausing the video will cause it to reappear.

I've also put a (commented out) line in there to show that it's not just based on the click, it occurs when `play()` is called via `setTimeout` too.

Anyways, have a play and tell me what you think.

Thanks!

Wayne

(Ooo - and the other video is there to show that the another element which is identical apart from the `controls` attribute works fine

Comment: Also! Just to show you, if you go to http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/#toc-markup and modify the .webm one to take the `controls` attribute out, then click **run code**, then right-click on the video and select Play _(from the browser context menu!)_ and the same thing happens.

Comment: It shows for me when I take controls out, but if I add "autoplay" the video disappears.

Comment: This bug appears to still be there in Chrome 29.0.

Comment: Still seeing this bug in Chrome 30 (as part of a script which calls `.play()` on a video when a certain scroll depth is reached). Scroll past the waypoint and it starts playing as normal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well I may as well answer my own question in case anyone needs it in the future.

It **IS** a bug, it works fine in Chrome 19.

My workaround in this case was to check if there was a control attribute, if not add it, play the video then remove the control attribute.

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/trolleymusic/vhgss/

```
playVideo = function(el) {
    if (!el) { return; }
    if (el.getAttribute('controls') !== 'true') {
        el.setAttribute('controls', 'true');                    
    }
    el.paused ? el.play() : el.pause();
    el.removeAttribute('controls');
}
```

Comment: It seems that it is enough to merely add and then remove the `controls` attribute once when the page is loaded.

Comment: Is this bug still a problem?

Answer (score 1):

This does seem to be a bug.  I have worked around this by manually tickling the play method in
$(document).ready for all my videos instead of adding the autoplay tag:

```
('#videoId').get(0).play()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've reported this bug to the Chromium project. In the meantime, as a workaround (still present in Chrome 30), I added controls to all video elements on the page, but applied a class called `animation` to those that will be triggered indirectly by events on the page (like scroll depth) rather than directly by the user.

```
<video class="animation" preload controls>
```

I then removed the controls from `.animations` using jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('video.animation').removeAttr('controls');
});
```

This solves the issue while we're waiting on a [fix for the regression](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=311757).