# Multiple videos with the same URL are not working well with poster attribute

Tags: html, video

The `poster` attribute is working as expected when I have one instance of my video. However in my case, I need to show the same video multiple times, in different formats.

When I click play on the preloaded video all following video posters are set to the first frame of the video.

Which means that if I have 4 times the same video and all 4 have their videos preloaded and I click play on the 2nd one, video number 1 will retain the poster display, video 2 will start playing and video 3 and 4 will remove their poster display in favour of the first frame of the video. This does not seem to be the expected behaviour.

I was able to fix this issue by changing the `preload` tag to `none`, but I prefer having it preloaded.

thoughts?

Comment: Does this happen in different browsers as well? Either way you might have to use JavaScript to make the other video instances synchronized to the first one. Depends on the player you are using.

Comment: @PeterKrebs, thanks for answerings, I actually found that my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492198/video-disappears-when-poster-attribute-and-preload-is-defined. And yes it works  fine on FireFox :)